# Yaml with bash: escaping quotes in string

Tags: bash, yaml, travis-ci

I want to execute command in travis file, it's executed by bash from yaml configuration file:

```
before_script:
 - psql -c 'create role "user" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD '1234'' -U postgres
```

But apparently I get the error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""1234""` and I just don't know how to escape quotes: `'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a yaml issue, it only concerns the shell launched by your travis build.

Single quotes inside single quotes in a shell string are escaped as a double single quotes (see [this link](https://linuxhint.com/bash_escape_quotes/) out of many others for more info)

```
psql -c 'create role "user" WITH LOGIN PASSWORD ''1234''' -U postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes its better to validate YAML syntax and it might surprise you with reasons its failing:

Use this great tool: [YAML Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/yaml-formatter)